# How can I read a file from JavaScript code running in Duktape?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, io, duktape

I am trying to port some code from Node.js to Duktape - does Duktape have a function equivalent to Node's [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/blob/master/examples/eventloop/fileio.c